# nginx Basic Authentication configuration on windows can't find user in auth_basic_user_file

Tags: windows, nginx, http-basic-authentication

I'm trying to set up basic authentication on an nginx 1.14.2 server on a Windows 7 machine.

Here's my test configuration:

```
worker_processes  1;

events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}

http {
    include       mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    sendfile        on;

    keepalive_timeout  65;

    server {
        listen       8282;

        auth_basic              "Restricted";
        auth_basic_user_file    .htpasswd;

        location / {
            root   html;
            index  index.html index.htm;
        }
    }
}
```

I am presented with a login box when I visit the website as expected but the authentication always fails. This error comes up in the error logs:

```
2019/01/24 16:47:55 [error] 178984#159308: *1 user "test" was not found in "C:\path-to-nginx/conf/.htpasswd", client: 127.0.0.1, server: , request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", host: "localhost:8282"
```

The path is correct, I validated that by putting an invalid path in `auth_basic_user_file` and observing a different error message.

This is the content of my .htpasswd (passwords are `abc123` and `test` respectively)

```
user:$apr1$xQVhJhiA$MCeALGvCxI0bXIcEfYpTR/
test:$apr1$UFI.GptK$v3aa644WePbta3a4ClR2R0
```

I tried changing newlines from `\r\n` to `\n` and it didn't help.

Is there anything wrong in my configuration that I missed? Or anything I can try to further debug this issue?

The idea is to eventually use nginx as a reverse proxy to authenticate a resource that doesn't support it, but I'm trying authentication on the most simple configuration possible first.